# for each li element, append a random AJAX item from XML

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

I'm trying to append a random item from an XML document to each li item in an ul, using AJAX , but I don't really know where to start, or if this is even possible. So in other words, for each li element, grab a random XML item and append it to the list item.

So far my script looks like this with the html being just a blank ul, I'm not receiving any errors so I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myxmlpage.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    }); 
});

function parseXml(xml){
    var random;
    $(xml).find("item:eq(" + random + ")").each(function(){
        random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);  
        $('ul').append("<li>" + $(this).find("item").text() + "</li>");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function parseXml(xml){
    var random;

    var $items = $(xml).find('item');
    var itemsCount = $items.length;

    $('ul li').each(function(){
         var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*itemsCount);
         $(this).html($($items.get(random)).text());
    });
}
```